How to add a reg file into Intune App Packager using Powershell?
Can anyone advise me on how I can add the below REG file to an MSI I wish to package on Intune using IntuneWinAppUtil? I understand that Powershell could be utilised, but I have never used it before for registry and not sure how best to do this?
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Sahara\Lynx 4\OrganizationDefaults]
"Lynx4Code"="CPS-Prod-Key-123456789"
"Name"="The Management Team"
"Email"="office@orgdomain.com"
"Organisation"="Org Name"
"Address"="Org Address"
"PostCode"="P0STC0D3"
"Country"="GB"
"LynxTerms"="true"
"SerialNumber"=""
"Trial"="false"

Searched for online guidance but nothing is working.

Learn how to use New-ItemProperty

this should be simplest but remember that you need to run it as admin or system to write at this path
    # Define the registry path
$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Sahara\Lynx 4\OrganizationDefaults"

# Ensure the registry path exists
if (-not (Test-Path $RegistryPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Force
}

# Add registry values
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Lynx4Code" -Value "CPS-Prod-Key-123456789"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Name" -Value "The Management Team"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Email" -Value "office@orgdomain.com"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Organisation" -Value "Org Name"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Address" -Value "Org Address"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "PostCode" -Value "P0STC0D3"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Country" -Value "GB"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "LynxTerms" -Value "true"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "SerialNumber" -Value ""
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPath -Name "Trial" -Value "false"

Write-Host "Registry entries added successfully."

